# Should Bootstrap .row contain .col-*?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, row, col

I want to fill `.row` by some content, should I always use `<div class='col-*'>Content</div>` or may I just put my `Content` into `.row`?

What are pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [bootstrap documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works) **"Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows."**

So no, it is not recommended that you place any content directly inside of row.

Answer (score 0):

The intended role of the row class is to contain and clear the floats of your columns. It is recommended to use the `col-*` classes inside if you want to assure control over the different screen sizes, and full responsiveness of your display. You can still put whatever you want inside a `.row`, but bootstrap advises you otherwise